# Homology and grading of filtered complex

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C_\bullet$ be a chain complex and $F_0C_\bullet$ is a subcomplex. Hence, we have a short exact sequence
$$0\to F_0C_\bullet\to C_\bullet\to C_\bullet/F_0C_\bullet \to0$$

We also get a graded associated complexes $Gr_0C_\bullet:=F_0C_\bullet$ and $Gr_1C_\bullet:=C_\bullet/F_0C_\bullet$.

From the long exact sequence of homology, we extract $\delta:H_{i+1}(Gr_1C_\bullet)\to H_{i}(Gr_0C_\bullet)$.

We define $Gr_0H_i(C_\bullet):=\{c\in H_i(C_\bullet)\mid s\in F_0C_i, c=[s]\}$, similarly for $Gr_1H_i(C_\bullet)$.

Why is it true that $\ker(\delta)=Gr_1H_{i+1}(C_\bullet)$ and $\mathrm{coker}(\delta)=Gr_0H_{i}(C_\bullet)$? (I was reading [this note](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ehutching/teach/215b-2011/ss.pdf), if I am not mistaken, I think they means this at the end of chapter 1.)

I think I got it. I was only focusing on the $\delta$ because I was "misled" by the note where they only write down the $\delta$. But we should consider the long exact sequence instead:

$$H_{i+1}(Gr_0C_\bullet)\xrightarrow{a}H_{i+1}(C_\bullet)\xrightarrow{b} H_{i+1}(Gr_1C_\bullet)\xrightarrow{\delta}H_{i}(Gr_0C_\bullet)\xrightarrow{c}H_{i}(C_\bullet)\xrightarrow{d} H_{i}(Gr_1C_\bullet).$$

$\mathrm{ker}(\delta)=\mathrm{im}(b)\cong H_{i+1}(C_\bullet)/\mathrm{ker}(b)=H_{i+1}(C_\bullet)/\mathrm{im}(a)$ and $\mathrm{coker}(\delta)= H_{i}(Gr_0C_\bullet)/\mathrm{im}(\delta)=H_{i}(Gr_0C_\bullet)/\mathrm{ker}(c)\cong\mathrm{im}(c)$. The image of $a,c$ are exactly $Gr_0H_{*}(C_\bullet)$ (by going to the chain complex level).